# I want to load and boot the Image of Vxworks from ZC702 Zynq Platfrom QSPI flash

Tags: embedded, xilinx, spi, vxworks, zynq

I want to load and boot the Image of Vxworks from ZC702 Zynq Platfrom QSPI flash, Can any one either point me to a step by step guide or a document which tells the:

1) Configuration needed to use SPI flash as the booting memory instead of SD card?

2)How to load Vxworks image into SPI flash ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling just to get a zc706 to boot from an SD card. I have found errors in the Windriver documentation but haven't figured out how to make it work though. That said if you have SD card working the VxWorks target.ref file in the BSP folder says:

> 3.7 Programming on board QSPI FLASH
>
> Rename BOOT.Bin to bootrom.bin, then copy u-boot BOOT.BIN to the root directory
>       of a SD card. Type the following commands in the U-Boot shell.
>
> ```
> mmcinfo;fatload mmc 0 0x8000000 bootrom.bin
> sf probe 0
> sf erase 0 0x0100000
> sf write 0x08000000 0 0x0FFFFF
> ```
>
> Note: if the bootrom size exceeds 0x100000 (1M), you should erase
>       one or more sectors and program more data to flash, for example:
>
> ```
> sf erase 0 0x0200000
> sf write 0x08000000 0 0x1FFFFF
> ```
>
> change the switch settings to boot from qspi flash setting and reset board.

Also see the Xilinx Appnote [Using VxWorks BSP with Zynq-7000 AP SoC](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1158-zynq-7000-vxworks-bsp.pdf)

If you make headway let me know!